# Delete this answer?

Tags: discussion

I asked the question owner to switch the accepted answer to the one that's actually open.

Should we delete this answer, which has nothing to do with open data?

https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/12225/1511

Because it's from a user without any history, on this site or others, it's also could be a self-promotion thing.